# Как передается аргумент функции?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, разбираю код и никак не могу понять, каким образом в аргумент функции передался eventObj, разве функцию не вызывают отдельно с аргументами?
откуда переменная хранит в себе event?

я понимаю, если написать вот так

```
function doSomething(event) {
// event - будет содержать объект события
}
element.onclick = doSomething;
```

мой код ниже

```
function init(){
    let button = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
    for (let i=0;i<button.length;i++){
        button[i].onclick = sendRequest;    
    }
}

function sendRequest(eventObj){

    let buttonClickID = eventObj.target.id;
    console.log(buttonClickID);
}
```

Comment: потому, что `event` есть `window.event`, он глобальный. И если вы передаете функцию в событие, то через прототип присваевается аргумент ивента.

Comment: а как это будет выглядеть? не могу понять все еще